Are there ways to get upper and lower bounds on the cardinality of a finite collection of finite sets?
Lets say I have a collection of finite sets $A_1, \ldots, A_n$.
Say you have conditions on the cardinality of the sets $A_i, i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$. For example, say each set $A_i$ is has cardinality either $2, 3$ or $4$ (only non negative integer values). Also, each element from $|A_1 \cup \ldots \cup A_n|$ appears in 3 of the $A_i$.
Is there a way to use the the principle of inclusion exclusion / optimization to use the conditions on each $A_i$ to get a maximum / minimum / range of possible value of $|A_1 \cup \ldots \cup A_n|$?
If it's not feasible to attain a minumum/maximum value, what about general upper/lower bounds?

Is something missing? Isn't the maximum always $4n$, attained when the sets $A_i$ are distinct and have $4$ elements each. And the minimum is $2$, when all the sets $A_i$ share the same two elements.

@JyrkiLahtonen I updated condition in second paragraph, thank you for pointing out.

Maybe the Bonferroni inequality? https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BonferroniInequalities.html

Making a huge leap of logic (and so I might be wrong), this seems to be a contest-math-esque type of question where you'd have to use double counting, incidence matrix, or even linear algebra to get at the answer. Can you specify the problem in its entirety?  $\quad$ EG By double counting (and a generous interpretation of what you wrote), the number of elements is  $\sum |A_i| / 3$, which is bounded between $2n/3, 4n/3$.

@Frazer I'm not saying that it is a competition problem. I'm mentioning that there are other techniques instead of PIE / optimization that could be applied. EG Kedar used a type of double-counting similar to what I described.  $\quad$ So, my belief is that if you properly state what you want to achieve (Are you trying to construct the sets? Are you trying to maximize the number of $A_i$? minimize the number of elements?), then others might provide more insight.

@CalvinLin I am trying to find a range of possible values for $|A_1 \ldots \cup A_n|$ given that stated conditions.  Preferably the greatest lower bound and least upper bound. What would you like further clarification on?

1/ Does each element appear in exactly 3 subsets? $\quad$ 2/ (If yes,) I gave the bound of $2n/3, 4n/3$, does that meet your needs? (EG Are you asking for a construction, or are these limits enough)

Like I said, double counting.  Basically, $|\cup A_i| = \sum |A_i| / 3$ and $  2n \leq \sum |A_i| \leq 4n$.  That's also what Kedar mentioned (without the clarify of "exactly 3 subsets". $\quad$ Yes, your new version doesn't make sense. EG If $A_1, A_1^c$ both only have 2, 3, or 4 elements, then clearly $|S| = |A_1 \cup A_1^c| $ is from 4 to 8.

When you say each element appears thrice, I'm assuming you mean at least thrice. (If exactly thrice, you can exactly calculate $|\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_i|$ as $\frac{\sum_{j=1}^{n}|A_j|}{3}$).
In simple words, if you count all the elements of the individual sets, you are counting each element in the union at least thrice. So, $\sum_{j=1}^{n}|A_j| \geq 3|\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_i|$).
And, $|\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_i| \geq \max\{|A_j|: 1\leq j \leq n\}$, since the cardinality of the union is greater than that of each individual set. The equality is achievable with your conditions, as shown below.
If you want to prove it rigorously, here's a formal proof:
Upper Bound
We take the disjoint union of these sets: $\bigsqcup_{j=1}^{n}A_j = \{(x,i): x \in A_i\}$. Then define the map $f:\bigsqcup_{j=1}^{n}A_j \rightarrow \bigcup_{i=j}^{n}A_j$, taking $(x,j)$ to $x$.
$$\bigsqcup_{j=1}^{n}A_j = \bigsqcup_{x\in \bigcup_{i=1}^nA_i} f^{-1}(\{x\}) \quad \implies \quad \sum_{j=1}^{n}|A_j| = \sum_{x\in \bigcup_{i=1}^nA_i}|f^{-1}(\{x\})|$$
Since each $x \in \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_i$ appears in at least  $3 \text{ }A_i$s, $$|f^{-1}(\{x\})| \geq 3 \text{ or equivalently, } \frac{1}{|f^{-1}(\{x\})|} \leq \frac{1}{3} \quad \forall x \in \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_i$$
So, we have $$|\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_i| = \sum_{x\in \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_i} 1 = \sum_{x\in \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_i} \frac{|f^{-1}(\{x\})|}{|f^{-1}(\{x\})|} \leq \frac{\sum_{x\in \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_i}|f^{-1}(\{x\})|}{3} = \frac{|\bigsqcup_{j=1}^{n}A_j|}{3} = \frac{\sum_{j=1}^{n}|A_j|}{3}$$
$$ \implies \quad |\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_i| \leq \frac{\sum_{j=1}^{n}|A_j|}{3}$$ and the equality hods if and only if $|f^{-1}(\{x\})| = 3, \text{    } \forall x$, i.e., each element in $\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_i$ is there in exactly  $3 \text{ } A_i \text{s}$.
Lower Bound
Since $A_j \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_i \text{    } \forall j, \text{ we have } |A_j| \leq |\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_i| \text{    } \forall j$ and hence $$|\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_i| \geq \max\{|A_j|: 1\leq j \leq n\}$$
This is in fact the best (greatest) lower bound, given the conditions of the problem. If you are given the cardinalities of each $A_i$, then along with the condition that each $x$ in the union be in at least 3 sets of the collection, you can always construct the collection so that $|\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_i| = \max\{|A_j|: 1\leq j \leq n\}$. Here's how:
Since each $x \in A_j$ is there in at least two of the remaining $A_i$s,
$$|A_j| \leq 2\sum_{i\neq j}|A_i|, \text{    } \forall j$$
So, if $M$ is the index for which $|A_M| = \max\{|A_j|: 1\leq j \leq n\}$, then:
$$A_M = \{y_1, y_2\, \ldots y_{|A_M|}\}, \text{  and  } |A_M| \leq 2\sum_{i\neq j}|A_i|$$
So, you can construct the remaining sets using only the elements of $A_M$, with each element of $A_M$ repeating at least twice, thereby satisfying the condition.
To summarize, $$\frac{\sum_{j=1}^{n}|A_j|}{3} \geq |\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_i| \geq \max\{|A_j|: 1\leq j \leq n\}$$
These are in fact the maximum and minimum values attainable, given the conditions.
